# How do define what data updates in a data extension when using "Update" query in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I have a data extension that is built by a SQL query. The automation runs daily to add/update data.

Its appointment data so what im trying to understand is what defines if a field is updated or not? My query runs fine however once data is populated if the time changes it doesn't get updated.

It uses a match key of subscriber key and appointment key as they could have more than one appointment

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rows are being updated based on your primary key(s). Both your subscriber key and appointment ID should be selected as primary keys in the destination data extension. So if your data is not being updated, then either only one of the above fields is selected as primary key in data extension, your row matching the keys is missing, or the field to be updated is not part of your SELECT statement.

A good way of verifying the latter will be by editing the query in Query Studio, which can be installed from [App Exchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FP3yFUAT)

Comment: It was my mistake, I had the primary key on appointment date so as this was what i needed to be updated, it wouldn't match to update. Corrected the primary key and working correctly, thanks